# Load words from a file into an Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, random, struct

I have a 80k+ file that I want to generate a random word from. I want to load this file into an array to generate a random word from. How can I do this. I've already opened the file, and generated a random number to correspond with the array.

Thanks

Comment: So you've got a random number, and an opened file.... what are you missing?

Comment: Pretty sure he just wants it tokenized.

Comment: So i need to init an array. but how do I load the fiile into the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the file is a dictionary. So, you have to read the file word by word - i.e. line by line if there is a word per line - copy each word in a string array (a char matrix) you preallocated and then you can use each random number as an index to access the string array and pick the "random" word.

```
size_t bytes = 0
char array[MAX_ROW][MAX_LEN+1] = {0};
file = fopen("filename", "r");
bytes = fread(array, MAX_ROW, MAX_LEN, file);
```

Comment: to copy strings, have a look to string.h functions  
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string#Function_overview

Comment: what code should i use to load content of file from pointer *file into string *dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

```
file = fopen('/path/file/', "r");
raed = fread( array, len, size, file);

printf("Look I can make it work, me");
```

Comment: so raed is the name of the array?

Comment: Most likely ARRAY is, raed is the number of elements with len length read from file